# Reversing a string word by word without use of built in function

Tags: java, string

I have written a program which is not working to revere the string word by word.

Input:

> This is a boy

Expected output:

> boy a is This

Output received:

> boy a boy is a boy

Can you help me complete/correct the code?

```
public class Title {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String rev = "This is a boy";
        char a[] = new char[rev.length()];
        int i, j;
        for (i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            a[i] = rev.charAt(i);
            if (a[i] == ' ' || i == ' ') {
                for (j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                    a[j] = rev.charAt(j);
                }
                String n = new String(a);
                System.out.print(n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, tell us why your code is wrong. I'm assuming the input and output you're showing us isn't what's actually being run

Comment: this program is not giving the expected output.

Comment: What output is the program giving.

Comment: @icantcode Do you consider `string.split()` as a built in function?

Comment: i don't want to us any function. would appreciate if we can go by my code to solve this

Comment: @icantcode I looked through you codes, I am afraid it can't be done if you want us to work on your current codes. The whole code needs to be changed.

Comment: Your code uses some strange logic. For example, in this statement: `if (a[i] == ' ' || i == ' ')`, you're checking if `i` is equal to a whitespace char... but `i` is an int, which means that `' '` will be promoted to an integer (probably 32, from ASCII)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

1. method:

   Check there is any space, if there is any, then copy char to other array. And the last for the 1st word, use other section to copy it because there is no space at the 1st character:

   ```
   public class Title {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
           String rev = "This is a boy";
           char a[] = new char[rev.length()];
           int i, j;
           int index =0;
           int previous = a.length;
           for (i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
               if (rev.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {
                   for (j = i + 1; j < previous; j++) {
                       a[index] = rev.charAt(j);
                       index ++;
                   }
                   a[index++] = ' ';
                   previous = i;
               }
           }
           for (j = 0; j < previous; j++) {
               a[index] = rev.charAt(j);
               index ++;
           }
           String n = new String(a);
           System.out.print(n);
       }
   }
   ```
2. method:

   First split the string and then print it in a reverse order:

   ```
   public class Title {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
           String rev = "This is a boy";
           String []a = rev.split(" ");

           for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
               if (i == a.length-1)
                   System.out.print(a[i]);
               else
                   System.out.print(" "+a[i]);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: guys i have added the check for last word like this, please let me know if it's correct or not:if(i==0)
   {
    for(j=i;j<previousLength;j++)
    {
     a[index]=start.charAt(j);
     index++;
    }
   }

Comment: okay one more query in the indexx++ thing.  index ++; so suppose my last word is *GO* and after coming out of a[index]= a[1] it will do an index++ that is index value will set to 3. in the next statement you are again calculating value of a[index++] i.e a[4] and setting it to whitespace. then you assign next character when the loop starts again. how did we get a space at index=3 then?

Comment: Let me explain clearly again
Suppose the last word is *go*
1) index=0
a[o]=g
index=index+1=0+1=1
2) index=1
a[1]=o
index=index+1=1+1=2

after this comes out of the loop
then we have a[index++]=‘ ‘
that means a[2+1]=a[3]=‘ ’ and then later this is assigned to next character via loop.
How and where is a[2] assigned as a space character in this.
also what’s the use and meaning of setting a[index++] to a space character.

Comment: `a[index++]` means a[index]=' ' , index ++;

Comment: Oh cool, can you break down and explain me the generalization of this form a[index++]

Answer (score 3):

It is always good approach to separate functionality into lower-level functions and then use them. It is more readable, easier to test and fix.

In your case, this can be done for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "This is a boy";
    List<String> separated = separateWords(input);
    for (int i = separated.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(separated.get(i));
        if (i != 0){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}   

public static List<String> separateWords(String line) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String actualString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if ((line.charAt(i) == ' ') || (i == line.length() - 1)) {
            if (i == line.length() - 1){
                actualString += line.charAt(i);
            }
            list.add(actualString);
            actualString = "";
        } else {
            actualString += line.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

---

Also if you insist on "your" solution, the most important thing you are missing is "end". In my case, it is variable "max". It remembers the end of word you want to copy.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String rev = "This is a boy";
    String out = "";

    int skipSpace = 1;
    int max = rev.length();
    for (int i = rev.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (rev.charAt(i) == ' ' || i == 0) {                
            if (i==0){
                skipSpace = 0;
            }
            for (int j = i + skipSpace; j < max; j++) {
                out += rev.charAt(j);
            }
            if (i != 0) {
                out += " ";
            }
            max = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tested and confirmed working, and it does not use any String functions other than `length()` and `charAt(int)` (both of which you also used, so I assumed it was okay):

```
public static void main(String []args){
    String rev = "This is a boy";
    String currentWord = "";

    for (int i=rev.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if (rev.charAt(i) == ' ')
        {
            printWordReversed(currentWord);
            currentWord = "";
        }
        else
            currentWord = currentWord + rev.charAt(i);
    }

    // Have to print out the last word
    printWordReversed(currentWord);
    System.out.println(); // new line for formatting
 }

 public static void printWordReversed(String word)
 {
     for(int i=word.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
     {
         System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
     }
     System.out.print(" ");
 }
```

[Java fiddle](http://goo.gl/oVD3V1)

The way this works is by storing the current "word" in a string as you loop through each character in the string. As soon as you hit a whitespace, print and clear the current word. However, since we're iterating through the string backwards, the word we extract is going to have the characters in reverse order, so we have to re-reverse them.

Comment: it uses `charAt(int)` too

Comment: Ah, true. Luckily OP used that one too, so I think I'm still okay. I'll edit my answer to point that out though.

Answer (score 2):

Read the words from backwards and store them in separate `String`, as you encounter the `whitespace`. Add the `whitespace` separately once the word is added to the `reverseString`.

```
public class Title {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    String str = "This is a boy";
    String tmp = "";
    String reverString = "";
    for(int i =str.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
      tmp += i!=0 ? str.charAt(i) : str.charAt(i) + " ";  // store the words in tmp;
      if(str.charAt(i) == ' '|| i==0) {                   // once whitespace occure, store in reverseString
        for(int j=tmp.length()-2; j>=0; j--){            // start with length()-2, because last char is whitespace.
          reverString += tmp.charAt(j);
        }
        if (i != 0)
          reverString = reverString + " ";              // add the whitespace after each word except last word (This)
        tmp = "";
      }
    }
    System.out.println(reverString);
  }
}
```